# Distribution parameters in scipy vs usual distribution parameters

Tags: python, statistics, scipy

The SciPy.stats package parameterizes probability distributions with location and scale parameters, which is not typical for many distributions.

The basic question I have is: does there exist a source that lists many or most of the distributions in SciPy, their usual parameterizations, and the relationship between the usual parameterizations and SciPy parameterizations?

I've seen answers scattered throughout Stackoverflow and other sources for some distributions.

For some distributions, I can find no sources at all. For example, I'm not sure how the non-central Chi-Squared distribution degrees of freedom and non-centrality parameter relate to the scale and location parameters that SciPy uses. I don't even see it on the reference page for the distribution: http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.ncx2.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does the following page help:

http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-dev/reference/tutorial/stats/continuous.html#continuous-random-variables

The location/scale is a generic transformation applied *on top* of the usual distribution parameters, as explained in the tutorial:

http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-dev/reference/tutorial/stats.html

Comment: Thank you! This is essentially what I was looking for. I guess I need to improve my Google skills!